# Login failing with error 4060 from console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application

I'm trying to make console application that will reset rows values to 0 for one table.
I can connect to MSSQL with the correct user and execute the query without issue with MSSMS.

Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

//string connectionString = "Server = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDBNAMEB; Database = D; Trusted_Connection = True;";

string connectionString = "server=SERVER;database=DB;UID=USER;password=PASSWORD";

using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    cnn.Open();

    var query = @"UPDATE CurrentMenus SET Ate_today = 0";

    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cnn.Close();

}
```

Here is the Error:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): Cannot open database         "DB" requested by the
> login. The login failed.    Login failed for user 'USER'.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean  breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj,   Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler,     SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry,    SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides
> overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
> Program.$(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\mshapkaroski\Desktop\C#\Reset
> Meals\ResetMeals\ResetMeals\Program.cs:line 9
> ClientConnectionId:4923a01c-7fe4-4b23-b2eb-68d8b341d975   Error
> Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

What could be the problem?

I tried with the local connection string, but it doesn't work as well.

```
//string connectionString = "Server = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDBNAMEB; Database = D; Trusted_Connection = True;"
```

Comment: The login is failing. You need to find out *why*. Look at the SQL Server logs and find the authentication error, as the ones passed back to the application layer are intentionally vague. If you don't understand that error, then [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I did take a look at the logs: Error: 18456, Severity:14, State:38

Comment: That's not the error in the logs, that's the error *number* passed to the application layer. What is the authentication error in the logs?

Comment: @Maria, more specifically, look at the SQL Server error log. It will contain more specifics as to the cause of the login failure.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to login to your database server.
Try "`User Id`" instead of `UID`, and also `Trusted_Connection=False`

```
Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=someDatabase;User Id=someUser;password=1234;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

Make sure you can log in to the ssms with your user name and password.

Comment: From my laptop I can connect to the server with MSSMS with the connection string credentials (I even copy/paste server,username,password). Do I need to configure something on the server? This is the error I'm getting now: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'USER'.'